# JS for playing beep sound for notification not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, audio, get

I have a script which does an ajax call to receive notifications from some page.The data received in the callback function is an ***integer(0,1,2,3...)*** only which is the number of rows selected in the query . Please find the query I am using in the description below.

I am using the following JS  :

```
            function myFunction() {
                $.get("AjaxServicesNoty.aspx", function (data) {
                    var recievedCount = data;
                    var existingCount = $("lblEventCount").text();

                    if (existingCount == "") {
                        $(".lblEventCount").html(recievedCount);
                        $(".lblAcceptedCount").html(recievedCount);
                        var sound = new Audio("Sound/notificatonSound.wav"); // buffers automatically when created
                        sound.play();
                    }

                    else if (parseInt(recievedCount) > parseInt(existingCount)) {
                        $(".lblEventCount").html(recievedCount);
                        $(".lblAcceptedCount").html(recievedCount);
                        var sound = new Audio("Sound/notificatonSound.wav"); 
                        sound.play();
                    }

                    else {
                        $(".lblEventCount").html(existingCount);
                        $(".lblAcceptedCount").html(existingCount);
//                        var sound = new Audio("Sound/notificatonSound.wav"); 
//                        sound.play();
                    }
                });
            }
            setInterval(myFunction, 3000);
```

The sound plays fine ***now***. Now as the `setInterval()` function is called , every three seconds the beep keeps playing even though according to my `if-else` conditions . It shouldn't be playing so . It should be only played if there are new updates .

I have used the following query  :

```
public int getAcceptedCount(int CustomerID)
        {
            string query = @"SELECT Status
                            FROM    tblEventService
                            WHERE   EventID IN  (SELECT EventID FROM tblEvent WHERE (CustomerID = @cid)) AND (Status = 'Accepted' OR Status = 'Rejected')";

            List<SqlParameter> lstP = new List<SqlParameter>();

            lstP.Add(new SqlParameter("@cid", CustomerID));

            DataTable dt = DBUtility.SelectData(query, lstP);

            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                return dt.Rows.Count;
            }
            else 
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
```

The query selects all the rows whose `Status` is `Accepted or Rejected`. So if there are any new `Accepted or Rejected` events, the count will increase. And thus the JS should play the notification sound!

What am i doing wrong here ?

Comment: did you copy that link on the console and put it on the browser to make sure if you can get the audio file ? because error 404 means that the file isn't found !

Comment: freak! >_< I misspelled the file! But i have another problem. The sound keeps playing on every `3 seconds` because of the setInterval call . How do i handle that ? @Khalid

Comment: I think if you need to check for a notification after 3s, all you need to do is to work your code to play the sound only if there is a new notification. For example adding an array that contains the ids of the notifications, and you need to check if the id you get is on the array or not, if not then you can play the sound and display the message. I'm sure there are many ways, I've just tried to give you an example. Good Luck :)

Comment: can you post an example of the `data` you you get from the ajax query ?

Comment: It recieves only the number of rows selected in the ***query*** i.e. it returns only an integer!

Comment: The sound keeps playing irrespective of whether I am logged in or not ! So it keeps firing the beeps unnecessarily!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74653/discussion-between-abhishek-ghosh-and-khalid).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem on your code is this if statement `if (existingCount == "")` . if your `exisitingCount` should be an integer you don't have to test this, otherwise whenever your `exisitingCount` equals to `0` your sound will be played.

But if sometimes you can get an empty string then you can optimise your code and removing the first condition, and parse all the data before you start testing :

```
        function myFunction() {
            $.get("AjaxServicesNoty.aspx", function (data) {
                var recievedCount = parseInt(data);
                var existingCount = parseInt($("lblEventCount").text());

                if ( recievedCount > existingCount ) {
                    $(".lblEventCount").html(recievedCount);
                    $(".lblAcceptedCount").html(recievedCount);
                    var sound = new Audio("Sound/notificatonSound.wav"); 
                    sound.play();
                } else {
                    $(".lblEventCount").html(existingCount);
                    $(".lblAcceptedCount").html(existingCount);
                }
            });
        }
        setInterval(myFunction, 3000);
```

Comment: will not `parseInt($("lblEventCount").text());` throw an error when there is nothing set into the the label : `lblEventCount` ?

Comment: The if else you provided in your answer doesn't play the sound at all

Comment: simply because at one moment the `recievedCount` should be greater than `existingCount `

Comment: i put an alert like this `var value = parseInt($("lblEventCount").text()); alert(value)` . And the var `value` had nothing stored in it. The alert was empty. Why would that happen ?

Comment: try to debug step by step, the `existingCount` at first is 0 and will always be 0 until the `recievedCount` is greater. you forgot the `.` on the selector `$("lblEventCount")`

Comment: okkay this works fine! Thank you so much! (Y) The **`.`** was harassing me !! Will keep that in my mind now :)

Answer (score 0):

The browser is looking for the sound file at http://localhost:40825/EventManagement/Sound/notificationSound.wav. It sounds like the path is just wrong and the way you're referencing it in your JS is looking for a folder named Sound inside the folder the JS file is located (EventManagement).

Where exactly is this Sound folder located on your machine? If it's a sibling of the EventManagement folder, try `new Audio("../Sound/notificatonSound.wav");`. Otherwise, I'd just move that folder and audio inside the EventManagement folder :)

Comment: Thank you , but please see my updated question. The sound plays now . But plays at the wrong timing!